# Parsing CSV/Text file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file using perl, I need to read, add a new row (both into a empty file and to the file already consisting data) and delete the row/rows by matching a particular value, I wanted to do it using a inbuilt module only doesn't want to install a external new module.

Earlier I was trying it with using xml file but it required to install XML::Twig or XML::LibXML which I didn't want.

Is it possible through csv or text file.

Comment: Any particular reason to avoid great CPAN modules?

Comment: @MiguelPrz actually the script will be used by many users and they don't want any extra dependency so I am looking at a way so I have not to install any modules if it is possible.

Comment: I think it's better to learn how to distribute your code with external libs as part of your installation in Perl.

Comment: @MiguelPrz sorry, but  I din't get what you mean ??

Comment: Read this article: http://perltricks.com/article/58/2014/1/5/The-easy-way-to-build-stand-alone-Perl-apps

Answer (score 1):

You should use Text::CSV module. If you don't want to install it then you are left with split and tricky handling.

See this tutorial by Gabor: [How to read a CSV file using Perl?](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl)

Comment: thanks, can I perform the delete and update operation without installing the Text::CSV  and if not is it possible with .txt file without installing any module.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse CSV file into XML without installing new module. Here is how:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $CSVfile="customer.csv";


print "Input Csv file: $CSVfile \n";


my ($arrRef,$keys)= convertCsvToHash($CSVfile);
print Dumper($arrRef);


sub convertCsvToHash{
    my $file = shift;

    open(FILE, "$file");
    my @arr = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);

    my @hashArry;
    chomp($arr[0]);
    my @keys = split(',',$arr[0]);

    for my $i(1..$#arr){
            chomp($arr[$i]);
            my @splitRec = split(',',$arr[$i]);

            my $hash = {};
            for my $j(0..$#keys){
                    $hash->{$keys[$j]} = $splitRec[$j]
            }
            push @hashArry,$hash;
    }
    return \@hashArry, \@keys;
}
```

Comment: Your link is broken. And there is nothing about XML in this code.

Comment: copy paste error, Added direct link, Edit didn't accept link with name

Comment: @sandeep you didn't get my question I guess, this is not what I asked.